# Location of SQL scripts on DBFS in Databricks SQL

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I want to download all SQL scripts on Databricks SQL so that I can put them in a Git repository. Is there a way to download all of them programmatically? Alternatively, can someone guide me to their location on DBFS?

Thanks.

Comment: all SQL scripts - can you explain more - you mean notebook with sql code?

Comment: One can create queries on Databricks SQL. They are stored somewhere. I am just wondering if they could all be downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a REST API for [Databricks SQL queries](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/api/queries-dashboards.html#tag/Queries-Results) that you can use to export queries.

P.S. SQL queries aren't stored on DBFS